# GoogleCloudStorage Java API much slower than gsuitl cp for large files (20G)

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

It is taking 40+ minutes to move a 20G file to a google bucket using the java storage api.  It took 4 minutes when using gsutil cp.  Any idea where I might be going wrong with the java storage api?

First attempt with Java API.

```
    BlobInfo blobInfo = null;
    try (BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileToUpload))) {
        blobInfo =
            BlobInfo.newBuilder(bucketName, bucketFilePath)
                .setContentType("application/octet-stream")
                .setContentDisposition(String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", bucketFilePath))
                .setMd5(fileToUploadMd5)
                .build();
        try (WriteChannel writer = storage.writer(blobInfo, Storage.BlobWriteOption.md5Match())) {
            ByteStreams.copy(inputStream, Channels.newOutputStream(writer));
        }
    } catch (StorageException ex) {
        if (!(400 == ex.getCode() && "invalid".equals(ex.getReason()))) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Second Attempt with Java API

```
    BlobInfo blobInfo =
        BlobInfo.newBuilder(bucketName, bucketFilePath)
            .setContentType("application/octet-stream")
            .setContentDisposition(String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", bucketFilePath))
            .setMd5(fileToUploadMd5)
            .build();

    // Write the file to the bucket
    writeFileToBucket(storage, fileToUpload.toPath(), blobInfo);

private void writeFileToBucket(Storage storage, Path fileToUpload, BlobInfo blobInfo) throws Exception {
    // Code from : https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-
    // examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/storage/StorageExample.java
    if (Files.size(fileToUpload) > 1_000_000) {
        // When content is not available or large (1MB or more) it is recommended
        // to write it in chunks via the blob's channel writer.
        try (WriteChannel writer = storage.writer(blobInfo)) {
          byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
          try (InputStream input = Files.newInputStream(fileToUpload)) {
            int limit;
            while ((limit = input.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
              try {
                writer.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer, 0, limit));
              } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
              }
            }
          }
        }
      } else {
        byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(fileToUpload);
        // create the blob in one request.
        storage.create(blobInfo, bytes);
      }
}
```

Both Java API attempts took 40+ minutes.

gsutil code

gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file serviceAccountJsonKeyFile

gsutil cp fileToUpload gs://google-bucket-name

Answer (score 1):

GSutil has built in feature for optimizing the large file upload, especially by splitting it and by sending in parallel several parts to optimize the bandwidth.

More detail [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/optimizing-your-cloud-storage-performance-google-cloud-performance-atlas)

Similar features are hard to implement.

Comment: Is that true of the vanilla gsutil cp command that I used?  I am aware that there is a way to do composite uploads (gsutil -o GSUtil:parallel_composite_upload_threshold=150M ) But I did not use that option in my testing.

Comment: What's your gcloud sdk version?

Comment: For the gsuitl command it is Google Cloud SDK 242.0.0.  
For the java command I am using the jar files google-cloud 1.84.0, google-api-client 1.30.2

Comment: You have outdated GCloud sdk/ The latest one is 279, with th gsutil 4.47. You should have the 4.38 version of gsutil. And the parallel mode isn't deactiviated. Since the version 4.42, issue has been found with python3 ans some operating system and now this value is disabled by default.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how the version of gsutil is relevant.  My question is really about the java api and why that is so slow, I am just using gsutil here for comparison purposes.

Comment: Is gsutil being used under the covers by the Java API?

Comment: No, the common layer between gsutil and Java API (and others langages) is API call,  in REST or in grpc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase the buffer size.
With a 100MB buffer I am reaching an upload rate of 120MB/s.